# How to send long via socket from server to client in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

I have to make server and client aplication in c++, and server must send number when client connect to server. I have make this:
server aplication

```
// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

std::clog << "Sending numbery\n";
iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, (const char*)&numberToSend, iResult, 0);
if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
```

and client code

```
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
std::clog << "Conneted\n";
do {
    std::clog << "Waiting for number\n";
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, (char*)&recvNumber, sizeof(long long), 0);
    if (iResult > 0)
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    else
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

} while (iResult > 0);
```

When I run server aplication then run client aplication in server window I see "Sending number" and on client window I see "Connected Waiting for number" but in client app i can't recive number sended from server, anyone have an idea what's wrong? How to send data after client conect with server?

Comment: In the server, what is `iResult`? What is its value? What is `numberToSend`? What is its value?

Comment: long long  numberToSend = 100, int iResult and it's the result of the operation.

Comment: The number of things that can go wrong here is impressive, so you really have to keep your eye on the result codes. For example, asking for `sizeof(long long)` bytes does not mean you will get `sizeof(long long)` bytes. You will get no more than `sizeof(long long)` bytes. You could get 1 byte. You could get 6. if the option is available, set `MSG_WAITALL` in `recv`'s final parameter to force it to get exactly `sizeof(long long)` or an error.

Comment: "int iResult and it's the result of the operation"? ***What*** "operation"? It should be the number of bytes to send, i.e. `sizeof numberToSend`.

Comment: iResult is result of send operation

Comment: What? Not according to the code you show, it's `iSendResult`. I talk about `iResult` that you pass as an *argument* to the `send` function as the size of the data to send.

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works fine now, I had a flip on my eyes and I did not see this fail.